# Add custom styles to gutenberg editor without child theme

Tags: wordpress, styles, editor

I’m trying to add my custom styles file to make the editor as similar as possible to the frontend.
But I don’t use a child theme and I don’t want to, and if I place the file inside the theme folder it will get deleted when updating.
So, is there any other way to do this? Anybody has a solution?
I've tried placing it inside themes folder but I haven't been able to go up one level with add_editor_style()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly objective of Child Theme.

> A child theme allows you to change small aspects of your site’s appearance yet still preserve your theme’s look and functionality. To understand how child themes work it is first important to understand the relationship between parent and child themes.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/